# No author on the 2nd page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have seen an academic proposal which has the following style for headers:

- On the 1st page, there is no header.
- On the 2nd page, there is a header, but there is no author on the left
- From the 3rd page, there are always headers with author, title and page.

Could anyone tell me that if it is conventional to not have author on the 2nd page?

PS: the following code could reproduce the effects.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}

\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textwidth}{170mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{3mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm}

\lhead{\lhead{Author}}
\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Title}
% Foot
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
1 \lipsum*[1]

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your question is "if it is conventional to not have author on the 2nd page"? If that is your question then it is off-topic here and you should ask at [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com) instead. As for the answer: I have personally never seen it in proposals, maybe it is more common in particular fields (my research is Computer Science/Humanities oriented).

Comment: I don`t know, which class you use.

Comment: @uli fancyhdr package

Comment: There is an error in `\lhead{\lhead{Author}}`. It should be `\lhead{Author}`. Then on the second page you will see the author in the head.